# Is it possible to control time between the queue of sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using a trigger that checks the update of one table and sends an email. But this table is updated many times on a short period of time.

Is it possible to control the queue of the SQL Server setting the time between the emails to send?

For example my server accepts only 8 emails per second, more than that and the sender is blocked. Is it possible to configure SQL Server to send only 8 emails per second?

Comment: I would never do this personally, so I'll give this advice and say that it's bad advice: use [WAITFOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx) and wait 1/8 of a second. In any case it's probably better to do this from another layer, eg MSMQ or cook your own strategy...

Comment: Own strategy would for instance be a recurring job that runs every minute, and works down the queue (and waits where needed). Read about scheduling a job in SQL Server [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx).